# How to convert filter domain S to equation with T sampling?

Tags: matlab, simulink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVJiX.png)

This is band-pass filter
If lower frequency cut-off is 78.075 rad/s and higher frequency cut-off is 312.300
How to convert filter domain S to equation with T sampling? If i don't use function transfer

Comment: you mean how to do a inverse Laplace transform?

Answer (score 0):

Converting a filter from the continuous-time to the discrete-time is known as Tustin's method (bilinear transformation)...

You can use MATLAB or GNU Octave to do this. See 'c2d' function, which stands for "continuous to discrete."